# In R: How do I get the column names of a CSV file as a list and values as a list of lists

Tags: r, csv

So I get a dataframe from my csv file like this:

```
dataFrame = read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE)
```

and I am trying to get the column names (first row) using

```
columnNames = colnames(dataFrame)
```

I need to get the values in the dataframe in a list of lists where each sublist is a list of values without any headers.

e.g.

```
Values: [
    [
      "0",
      "0",
      "value",
      "value",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "0",
      "0",
      "value",
      "value",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0",
      "0"
    ]
  ]
```

Is there any way to do that?

I tried doing this

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dataFrame)) {
    temp = list(dataFrame[i])
    values <- c(values, temp)
}
```

but I keep getting each column name along with every entry.

Comment: In your example output, are those supposed to be rows from your data frame or columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dataframe contains only columns of the same type, e.g. only numeric, you can first coerce to a matrix and then set the column names (and row names if there are any) to NULL. Here's an example using the built-in mtcars dataframe:

```
foo <- mtcars
foo <- as.matrix(foo)
rownames(foo) <- NULL
colnames(foo) <- NULL
```

You can then convert to a list either using a loop similar to what you wrote or, in more "idiomatic" R using lapply:

```
foo <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(foo)), function(col) foo[,col])
```

Comment: Assuming it's what the OP wants, I'm not sure I'd call your last option idiomatic compared to `as.list(foo)`.

Comment: `as.list(foo)` does something different: it creates a list of the elements of foo, whereas the code I provided creates a list of the columns of foo.

Comment: Not if foo is the original data frame. The data frame was a list all along. No need for any looping or processing.

Comment: Yes, but the question asked how to remove the "headers" which I took to mean the column names. I'm not sure why the questioner wants to do this (it seems strange to me) but `as.list(foo)` leaves the column names.

Comment: The names can be removed from the list in one line with unname().

Comment: Yes that's a cleaner solution.

Comment: foo <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(foo)), function(row) foo[row,]) -> This works for rows. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're trying to do, given your comment above regarding wanting rows:

```
unname(lapply(split(mtcars,1:nrow(mtcars)),function(x) {unname(as.list(x))}))
```

This uses the built-in data set `mtcars`.

Comment: This works with numeric entries, but not with non-numeric entries. But thank you!!

Comment: @RitikaR No, my answer works with entries of any type.